# Costs ? How to, run Windows XP on Mac Mini via VMWare?

Tags: windows-xp, mac, osx-snow-leopard

Ideally I'm looking for a free or cheap solution where I can run windows XP on my mac mini. I don't mean dual boot, I mean from a program on snow leopard.

I've heard mention of vmware.

But I've no idea what I need and costs ?

I do have a spare license for Windows XP

Comment: Note that an OEM Windows XP license won't activate unless your forward the SMBIOS/DMI information to the virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is a free virtualization program. It is slightly slower than [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) or [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/), so if you're looking to play games, then you may want to invest in one of those products. If you're not running anything computationally heavy, then VirtualBox should work just fine.

All you need to do is choose one of these three products then install and run it.  Creating your first VM is relatively straightforward.